# make_lazy_gettext with wForms getting output .lazy_gettext at 0x07808D68>

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I have application on python 3.5 that use tornado 4.5.1, i got in trouble with custom errors given in wForms, i did a research and wForms says that have to be used lazy_gettex in order to be able to translate custom errors passed to wForm Class.

I found the module **speaklater** that have **make_lazy_gettext** , but using it i gett in another trouble, instead of the error message on the front end i get something like this **.lazy_gettext at 0x07808D68>**

My code handler: hanlders.py
**inside the handler i have available self._ for gettext translations that now they work**

```
class ChangePassword(ProfileHandler):
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChangePassword, self).initialize(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form = profile_f.ChangePasswordForm(meta=self.meta_locale)

    @authenticated(domain='c')
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        """::access::
        <div class="___sort">Profile</div>
        <div>
            <font class="__get__">GET</font>
            <i class="icon-arrow-right14"></i>
            <font class="desc">Change password</font>
        </div>
        ::
        ::auto_access::1::
        """
        response = yield self.model.item(_id=self.current_user)
        profile = response.get('user', {})
        response = yield self.quiz_m.get_all_quizzes(self.current_user)
        quizzes = response.get('quizzes', {})
        render_vars = {
            'form': self.form,
            'profile': profile,
            'quizzes': quizzes,
        }
        self.render('pages/profile/profile_edit_password.html', **render_vars)

    @authenticated(domain='c')
    @coroutine
    def post(self):
        """::access::
        <div class="___sort">Profile</div>
        <div>
            <font class="__post__">POST</font>
            <i class="icon-arrow-right14"></i>
            <font class="desc">Change password</font>
        </div>
        ::
        ::auto_access::1::
        """
        self.form.process(self.request.arguments)
        if self.form.validate():
            form_data = self.form.prepared_data
            update_response = yield self.model.update_password(
                self.current_user, new_password=form_data['new_password'], old_password=form_data['old_password']) # noqa
            if update_response['success']:
                # start send email
                user = yield self.model.mongo_find_one('users', ObjectId(self.current_user))
                render_vars = {
                    'user': user,
                    'new_password': form_data['new_password'],
                }
                yield emails_template.send_template(self, 'profile_password', render_vars, user['email'])
                # end send email
                self.redirect('/profile/')
                return
            else:
                self.form.set_foreign_errors({'old_password': update_response['errors']})
        response = yield self.model.item(_id=self.current_user)
        profile = response.get('user', {})
        response = yield self.quiz_m.get_all_quizzes(self.current_user)
        quizzes = response.get('quizzes', {})
        render_vars = {
            'form': self.form,
            'profile': profile,
            'quizzes': quizzes,
        }
        self.render('pages/profile/profile_edit_password.html', **render_vars)
```

My code below: forms.py

```
from copy import copy
from forms import BaseForm, vl, fl, CustomStringField
from forms import EmailValidator

from speaklater import make_lazy_gettext as _


class ChangePasswordForm(BaseForm):
    old_password = fl.PasswordField(validators=[vl.DataRequired(), vl.length(max=32, min=6)])
    new_password = fl.PasswordField(validators=[vl.DataRequired(), vl.length(max=32, min=6)])
    new_repassword = fl.PasswordField(validators=[vl.DataRequired(), vl.length(max=32, min=6)])

    def validate_new_repassword(self, field):
        if self.data.get('new_password') != field.data:
            raise vl.ValidationError(_('Incorrect retyped password'))
```

From the above code my custom error message is _('Incorrect retyped password') and the front end output i get this **.lazy_gettext at 0x07808D68>**

Any recommendation why this is happening?

**Function for simple gettext used in application**

```
def load_gettext_translations(dir_dom):
    # Todo: think about workaround
    """
    Like standard tornado.locale.load_gettext_translations but loads more locales from different locations
    :param dir_dom: {'directory': '', 'domain': '', 'prefix': ''}
    """
    import gettext
    # global _translations
    # global _supported_locales
    # global _use_gettext
    # _translations = {}
    for trans in dir_dom:
        for lang in os.listdir(trans['directory']):
            if lang.startswith('.'):
                continue  # skip .svn, etc
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(trans['directory'], lang)):
                continue
            try:
                os.stat(os.path.join(trans['directory'], lang, "LC_MESSAGES", trans['domain'] + ".mo"))
                tornado.locale._translations['%s%s' % (trans.get('prefix', ''), lang)] = gettext.translation(
                    trans['domain'], trans['directory'],
                    languages=[lang])
            except Exception as e:
                gen_log.error("Cannot load translation for '%s': %s", lang, str(e))
                continue
    tornado.locale._supported_locales = frozenset(list(tornado.locale._translations.keys()) + [tornado.locale._default_locale])
    tornado.locale._use_gettext = True
    gen_log.debug("Supported locales: %s", sorted(tornado.locale._supported_locales))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I've created a github repo as a demo for this answer. It can be found here: https://github.com/bhch/tornado-localization.

---

You are using it wrong. From the [`speaklater` docs](https://pypi.org/project/speaklater/) `make_lazy_gettext`, as its name suggests, makes a lazy gettext object. It does not return a string object, instead it returns a function. So, when you're doing:

```
msg = _('Message')

msg is in fact a function, not a lazy string
```

Correct usage will be like this:

```
from speaklater import make_lazy_gettext


def translate(message):
    """Function responsible for translating message"""

    return message # return message for the sake of example


_ = make_lazy_gettext(lambda: translate)

msg = _('Hello')

print(msg)
# outputs Hello
```

The `translate` function is responsible for translations. I've used a simple function just to demonstrate the use of speaklater. But in a real application it must be able to translate the given string depending on the language of the client.

---

**How translation works:**

It seems that you think using `_` or `gettext` automatically translates some message to any language.

No. That is not how translations work.

You will have to manually provide translations to all the messages you want to translate.

In the `translate()` function in the example above, you can implement translations for your messages by creating dictionaries like :

```
# spanish
{
  'es_ES': {'Incorrect retyped password': 'Contraseña reescrita incorrecta'}
  # do this for other languages you want to support
}
```

And write the appropriate code in the `translate()` function which will look for the translation in this dictionary according to the language (locale) and return the translated message.

---

If you want to provide support for many languages, writing dictionaries can be tiresome and rather impractical. For that purpose you can check out [`tornado-babel`](https://github.com/openlabs/tornado-babel) library to make things easier for you. Tornado also has support for [locale](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locale.html#tornado.locale.get). But that would be a little more work than using `tornado-babel`.

---

**Sample Tornado application**

One thing I should point out is that you can't use a global `_` object because Tornado is single threaded. You will need to make `_` object inside your handlers so that the locale stays different for each user.

```
from tornado import web, locale
from speaklater import make_lazy_gettext

class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # tornado handlers have a `self.locale` attribute
        # which returns the current user's locale
        _ = make_lazy_gettext(lambda: self.locale.translate)

        hello = _('hello')
        # do something else


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load the translation files
    locale.load_gettext_translations('/path/to/locale/', 'domain')
    # ...
```

You will also need to modify the `__init__` function of your `ChangePasswordForm` to accept the gettext object `_`.

Comment: thanks for helping yes now is returning me the string in English, the project is using gettext in order to collect the po file and i updated the code with the function is doing this, could u help me to create the translate function for lazy gettext please? please see my function above

Comment: i need to adjust the translate function please if u can help with it, based on current structure of .po files

Comment: i already have all this translated in my .po file, can u help to adjust the lazy function to use current po file and return the correct string?

Comment: @ionluchian I've added some sample code for use with Tornado. Take a look.

Comment: thanks, i am little confused, my tornado app already have translations with example i added, i have available in handlers _ with gettext but not the lazy gettex, i want now to implement inside form.py for each form the lazy gettext, i tried to add inside the form file but cant make it to work. could u explain little more please?

Comment: @ionluchian You can't *create* a global lazy gettext object in your forms file. That won't work because Tornado is single threaded and therefore it's value will keep changing multiple times even for one user. You will need to create it in your handlers so that each user will have a separate gettext object with separate language. Then pass it to your forms.

Comment: cant get it to work, let paste the handler and form as well

Comment: i added the entire handler get and post, as well inside handler i have available self._, maybe this will help, because do not get your point

Comment: @ionluchian Hi. As this answer has gotten very long, I've [posted the code at pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xRUP5Vt9) with some more comments to explain what's going on. Take a look.

Comment: i tried your example but the critical error is with def __init__ inside the form, is breaking down the form, as well locale.load_gettext_translations('/path/to/locale/', 'domain') is global available

Comment: your solution is correct but seems i do not have any luck to implement in my tornado app, i tried the following and is working, to give to the form a new field = None, give the needed translation inside the handler, and getting it inside the form

Comment: @ionluchian You can override the `__init__` method of your form to accept a `locale` argument. As for `locale.load_gettext_translations` being globally available, yest that is true. But that won't give you the locale of the current user who is browsing your site. That is why you need to get the locale in a handler using `self.locale`.

Comment: yes this i understood, but doing anything with lazy gettex my forms and app is breaking down, what code i can send you in order to reproduce the issue? as u saw in my example i already pass to the form this meta=self.meta_locale, so i already have locale there, if i try to add init in the form as u wrote all app crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171057/discussion-between-ionluchian-and-xyres).